# MySQL for excel has failing requirements while installation

Tags: microsoft-office, mysql, office365

During custom installation of MySQL, the installer tells me that  :
[MYSQl for excel has failing requirements. Microsoft Excel 2007 or higher is not installed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRdJo.png)
I already have office products installed on my system as part of Office365 subscription.
However, they are store apps. Is that the reason for MySQL not being able to detect excel installation.
How do you I get around this. Didn't come across a similar question on the forum. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I already have office products installed on my system as part of Office365 subscription. However, they are store apps. Is that the reason for MySQL not being able to detect excel installation.

You must be talking about the Windows Store and are running Windows 10 Version 1803

[image]

> The Centennial versions of the Office applications are more robust than the Universal Windows Platform (UWP) versions that previously have been available in the Windows Store. The Centennial Office apps, which will be 32-bit only, will support Office add-ins, and run COM add-ins on other versions of Windows 10.

[Source](https://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-readies-june-preview-of-its-full-featured-office-apps-coming-to-its-windows-education/)

The article was with regards to Windows 10 S, which has changed in the last year, but the article indicates that the Office found on the Windows Store on Windows 10 does indeed support add-ons like *MySQL for Excel* (but in this specific case the MySQL does not support the version of Office you have installed)

> How do you I get around this.

You don’t.  The MySQL installer needs to be updated to detect the version of Office you have installed.